# Javascript functions called in Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

While debugging a site, is there any way to have a stack-trace-like thing in order to have a view of all the functions called? For example, to know what happens when I click on a link?

I know some function is called but I don't know which.

Answer (score 3):

Go to scripts tab in google chrome developer tools and set an Event Listener Breakpoint to a click event (or whatever) and click upvote. It will then stop execution right away and you may manually walk through the whole execution process, function by function.

Answer (score 1):

`console.trace()` is your friend.

Comment: hmmm, i'm not talking about a site of mine. for example, imagine that i want to know what happens in stackoverflow when i click on "Add Comment" or on the "Upvote" arrow.